# Contar ocorrências de uma letra em uma string que se repete várias vezes até um limite de caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Nesse problema eu tenho que contar o número de vezes em que aparece a letra `'a'` na string `'a'` de range `1000000000000`, só que eu tenho `run time error` quando é um numero muito alto assim. por exemplo: se eu botar até `100000` eu consigo contar a quantidade de vezes, mas acima disso o meu código já não consegue ler mais

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    n_repetidos = n // len(s) + 1
    string_repetida = s * n_repetidos
    string_repetida_ate_n = string_repetida[:n]
    x = string_repetida_ate_n.count('a')
    return x

print(repeatedString('a', 1000000000000))
```

Um outro exemplo, se eu tenho uma string "aba" de range 10, a string com 10 letras fica "abaabaabaa", e eu tenho a ocorrência de 7 letras 'a'.

Answer (score 3):

```
string_repetida = s * n_repetidos
```

Nesta linha você está criando uma string nova que será a string `s` repetida `n_repetidos`. Não há porquê fazer isso, pois se a ideia é apenas contar a quantidade de ocorrências, você pode contar as ocorrências em `s` e aí sim multiplicar por `n_repetidos`. Como comentado, não tem porquê manter essa string inteira em memória.

Calculando quantas vezes a string se repetiu por completo e quantos caracteres parciais dela foram utilizados para completar a string final, você pode somar as ocorrências de forma bastante simples:

```
def repetir(s: str, n: int):
    # Verifica quantas vezes a string se repetiu por completo
    # E quantos caracteres foram usados para completar o total
    repetiu, sobrou = divmod(n, len(s))

    # Soma a quantidade de ocorrências em s vezes a quantidade que ela se repete
    # Mais a quantidade de ocorrências da string parcial
    return s.count('a') * repetiu + s[:sobrou].count('a')
```

Para `repetir('aba', 10)`, o valor de `repetiu` seria 3, pois a string `'aba'` se repetiu 3x por completo, enquanto `sobrou` seria 1, pois foi utilizado 1 caractere de `'aba'` para completar os 10 caracteres solicitados. Em `'aba'` a letra `'a'` aparece duas vezes, então se a palavra se repete 3 vezes, 2*3 = 6, mais as ocorrências na string parcial, `'a'`, que é uma vez. Assim, 6+1 = 7.

Answer (score 2):

Ao fazer `string_repetida = s * n_repetidos` você está criando uma string com 1 trilhão de caracteres (ou seja, se cada caractere ocupar 1 byte, será necessário 1 **terabyte** para esta string, por isso dá erro no seu teste, pois está estourando a memória).

Mas enfim, não precisa montar uma string gigante e depois fazer a contagem.

Uma alternativa à solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/487547/112052) é usar o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
 
def repeatedString(s, n):
    qtd = 0
    for letra in islice(cycle(s), n):
        if letra == "a":
            qtd += 1
    return qtd
 
print(repeatedString('aba', 10)) # 7
print(repeatedString('baa', 10)) # 6
```

Primeiro, `cycle(s)` cria um iterador que itera repetidamente pela string. Como ele cria um iterador infinito, eu uso `islice` para limitá-lo a somente os primeiros `n` elementos.

Depois, basta contar quantos são iguais a "a" e retornar o resultado.

---

Só que esta solução é mais ineficiente do que a outra resposta, principalmente se o `n` for muito grande (já que ela precisa iterar pelo *loop* `n` vezes, enquanto a outra resposta só faz alguns cálculos simples e itera pela string apenas para fazer o `count`).

Uma outra alternativa é, em vez de usar `count` 2 vezes (uma na string toda e outra na substring), fazer um único *loop* que contabiliza tudo de uma vez:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    repetiu, sobrou = divmod(n, len(s))
    qtd = 0

    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == 'a':
            qtd += repetiu
            if i < sobrou:
                qtd += 1
    return qtd
```

A ideia é similar à da outra resposta: vemos quantas vezes a string será repetida por completo, e quanto falta para completar o tamanho `n`.

Depois iteramos pelos caracteres dela e pelos índices ao mesmo tempo (usando [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para isso), e a cada vez que encontramos uma letra "a", já adicionamos a quantidade de vezes que a string se repete por completo. Depois, vemos se ainda precisa somar mais um, caso estejamos em uma posição que é usada para a "sobra".